# Find column that minimizes time difference

Tags: r, datetime

I'm trying to create a function that I could give a dataframe of datetimes, like the dfTdata data.frame below, specify a particular datetime column, like the trWindDateTime column, and have it return the other datetime column which had the smallest average difference from the first datetime column.  This combines two things I really struggle with, working with datetime columns in R and loops.  I have some code I found that I've been trying to hack together below.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```r
## Taking difference between specified column and all other columns in data.frame.  
# I know this code doesn't exactly do what I'm trying to accomplish here.  
# What I would like to do is pass it dfTdata and specifiy a column name, and have 
# it take the difference between that date column and all the others.

funcDiff <- function(x) {
  for(i in seq_along(x)) {
    x[, i] <- x[, i] - x[, (i+1)]
  }
}

## Creating data.frame of diff between columns
dfDateDiff <- funcDiff(dfTdata)

## Trying to take the mean for each column of differences
dfMeanDiff <- lapply(dfDateDiff, mean)

## Trying to return the column with the minimum average mean
ColNum <- which(dfMeanDiff == min(dfMeanDiff))
```

Data: `dput(dfTdata)`

```r
structure(list(TrWindDateTime = c(1422683580, 1422559320, 1423162920, 
    1423598220, 1423697880, 1423545300, 1424580900, 1424242200, 1426370640, 
    1426616460, 1426479960, 1426721700, 1427121780, 1428707940, 1430257500, 
    1432256100, 1433912820, 1435505100, 1437770880, 1440517860, 1440373200, 
    1440028200, 1446993480, 1449501900, 1449095520, 1449449340, 1450308780, 
    1449771840, 1438615980, 1439432400, 1440340980, 1440090360, 1440027300, 
    1439232120, 1440593340, 1438405920, 1442772900, 1443192720, 1443110040, 
    1443153600, 1441950840, 1443343800, 1443723720, 1445739720, 1443759360, 
    1444959300, 1444851960, 1445704920, 1443314280, 1443400980, 1443834480, 
    1445292540, 1447201440, 1447201560, 1447535460, 1447542600, 1448128440, 
    1446287220, 1445973000, 1448101560, 1447932900, 1446932220, 1447351680, 
    1447981980, 1447313160, 1447693140, 1447702980, 1447801140, 1446873960, 
    1447267260, 1446932700, 1448061660, 1447280580, 1447534680, 1446919980, 
    1447698180, 1447057440, 1447205880, 1447693440, 1447016700, 1448043660, 
    1447376220, 1447931340, 1449606480, 1448952120, 1448352120, 1448165040, 
    1450035060, 1449361860, 1450128060, 1449465540, 1449707520, 1449247140, 
    1449350520, 1449704160, 1449717180, 1449711360, 1449768540, 1449862440, 
    1449756300), WindDateTime = c(1422690780, 1422560640, 1423163280, 
    1423600200, 1423701000, 1423546920, 1424582880, 1424243460, 1426373160, 
    1426617000, 1426484820, 1426725600, 1427123580, 1428708420, 1430259240, 
    1432260660, 1433914800, 1435507800, NA, 1440519180, 1440373800, 
    1440028200, 1446994860, 1449503460, 1449098340, 1449449520, 1450310220, 
    1449772620, 1438616580, 1439432400, 1440341460, 1440090600, 1440028440, 
    1439232960, 1440594240, 1438406340, 1442774040, 1443193200, 1443110940, 
    1443154980, 1441952640, 1443353400, 1443724440, 1445740980, 1443761220, 
    1444962360, 1444853940, 1445705040, 1443316200, 1443402420, 1443835560, 
    1445293380, 1447202340, 1447202760, 1447535760, 1447543080, 1448130120, 
    1446287520, 1445974860, 1448101740, 1447945680, 1446934620, 1447353240, 
    1447984020, 1447313760, 1447693740, 1447705080, 1447801920, 1446874620, 
    1447271580, 1446933720, 1448066700, 1447283160, 1447534860, 1446920820, 
    1447699380, 1447058820, 1447207200, 1447694400, 1447017120, 1448044320, 
    1447376760, 1447931580, 1449607020, 1448952960, 1448354640, 1448167080, 
    1450036500, 1449363240, 1450128060, 1449466380, 1449707940, 1449247500, 
    1449357780, 1449704760, 1449718200, 1449712800, 1449769200, 1449864360, 
    1449758340), TomDateTime = c(1422688560, NA, 1423162980, 1423599540, 
    1423709640, NA, 1424580900, 1424242380, 1426380780, 1426617840, 
    1426486620, 1426722660, 1427122380, 1428709200, 1430257740, 1432275120, 
    1433921340, 1435508940, 1437769140, 1440517980, 1440373200, 1440027360, 
    1446993540, 1449503280, 1449097860, 1449449520, 1450310520, 1449773220, 
    1438616040, 1439431500, 1440342840, 1440091260, 1440027480, 1439232120, 
    1440593400, 1438407900, 1442781360, 1443193560, 1443110040, 1443153660, 
    1441951500, 1443352200, 1443724500, NA, 1443763380, 1444968780, 
    1444853580, 1445706240, 1443315420, 1443401340, 1443834540, 1445292540, 
    1447201440, 1447201620, 1447538340, 1447554360, 1448128800, 1446287220, 
    1445989380, 1448109540, 1447932900, 1446934260, 1447351800, 1447982520, 
    NA, 1447693500, 1447703040, 1447802640, 1446875880, 1447275360, 
    1446940440, 1448061720, 1447282320, 1447548840, 1446921780, 1447698240, 
    1447058280, 1447206540, 1447703700, 1447016760, 1448052060, 1447376220, 
    1447936920, 1449607500, 1448956380, 1448353920, 1448166120, 1450035900, 
    1449363540, 1450126920, 1449465540, 1449707580, 1449247500, 1449350520, 
    1449716460, 1449730920, 1449717120, 1449769200, 1449862740, 1449757320
    ), CircleDateTime = c(1422688740, 1422560280, NA, 1423599720, 1423707120, 
    1423546800, 1424591940, 1424242800, 1426380900, 1426617840, 1426484640, 
    1426724280, 1427122680, 1428708720, 1430257800, 1432260720, 1433921340, 
    1435509060, 1437770880, 1440518220, 1440373380, 1440030660, 1446993780, 
    1449503520, 1449097560, 1449449580, 1450310100, 1449772680, 1438616400, 
    1439431740, 1440343440, 1440091620, 1440027600, 1439232540, 1440594060, 
    1438408020, 1442781660, 1443195120, 1443110580, 1443153720, 1441952220, 
    1443353160, 1443725040, 1445740920, 1443763500, 1444965120, 1444853760, 
    1445706960, 1443315420, 1443401640, 1443835560, 1445292660, 1447201980, 
    1447201680, 1447538340, 1447542900, 1448128800, 1446287280, 1445991480, 
    1448110380, 1447932960, 1446934860, 1447353540, 1447982940, NA, 
    1447693320, 1447703220, 1447802820, 1446876000, 1447271820, 1446933480, 
    1448062020, 1447283100, 1447549020, 1446921300, 1447698300, 1447058280, 
    1447206840, 1447701300, 1447017240, 1448044320, 1447376340, 1447937700, 
    1449607380, 1448952840, 1448354280, 1448166960, 1450036800, 1449363300, 
    1450129380, 1449466020, 1449707820, 1449247680, 1449350640, 1449707100, 
    1449718440, 1449718500, 1449769920, 1449864600, 1449757560), 
    SteamDateTime = c(NA, 1422568800, 1423200600, 1423607880, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1426610820, 1426628100, 1426489860, NA, 1427138220, 
    1428715200, NA, NA, 1433922660, 1435511100, NA, 1440545100, 
    1440387480, NA, 1447015500, 1449516420, 1449100500, 1449453600, 
    1450328820, 1449777000, 1438638480, NA, 1440351900, 1440105240, 
    1440053760, 1439255400, 1440629040, 1438411500, 1442808420, 
    1443210900, 1443148620, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1445724660, 
    NA, NA, 1443856860, 1445314620, 1447225440, NA, 1447566360, 
    NA, NA, 1446309660, NA, 1448127000, 1447964100, 1446969300, 
    1447365240, NA, NA, 1447728960, 1447729620, NA, NA, 1447300020, 
    1446963840, 1448076900, NA, 1447572600, 1446937020, 1447717200, 
    1447100280, NA, 1447734360, 1447051080, 1448075040, 1447388280, 
    1447956000, 1449641580, NA, 1448412600, NA, 1450056840, 1449381360, 
    NA, NA, 1449736800, 1449273600, 1449390900, 1449719340, NA, 
    NA, 1449787440, NA, 1449772080), AnyDateTime = c(NA, 1422561120, 
    1423200180, 1423607880, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1426404420, 1426628100, 
    1426489860, 1426741080, 1427138220, 1428715200, NA, NA, 1433922660, 
    1435511100, 1437781680, 1440545100, 1440387480, NA, 1447015500, 
    1449516420, 1449100500, 1449453600, 1450328820, 1449777000, 
    1438638480, NA, 1440351900, 1440105240, 1440053760, 1439255400, 
    1440629040, 1438411500, 1442808420, 1443210900, 1443148620, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1445724660, NA, NA, 1443856860, 
    1445314620, 1447225440, NA, 1447566360, NA, NA, 1446309660, 
    NA, 1448127000, 1447964100, 1446969300, 1447365240, NA, NA, 
    1447728960, 1447729620, NA, NA, 1447300020, 1446963840, 1448076900, 
    NA, 1447572600, 1446937020, 1447717200, 1447100280, NA, 1447734360, 
    1447051080, 1448075040, 1447388280, 1447956000, 1449641580, 
    NA, 1448412600, NA, 1450056840, 1449381360, NA, NA, 1449736800, 
    1449273600, 1449390900, 1449719340, NA, NA, 1449787440, 1449894600, 
    1449772080)), .Names = c("TrWindDateTime", "WindDateTime", 
    "TomDateTime", "CircleDateTime", "SteamDateTime", "AnyDateTime"
    ), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after? You pass it the name of the reference column as a string, and tell it what exactly you want out. If defaults to giving you the column with the smallest (absolute value) time difference between it and the reference column. You can also ask it for just the name of the column, or for the name of the column and the difference between your reference column and the output column.

```
    # Run this to convert to POSIXct
    library('lubridate')
    library('magrittr') # this is just for the first pipe
    dfTdata <- lapply(dfTdata, function(x) as.POSIXct(x, origin = '1970-01-01')) %>% as.data.frame(.)

    funcDiff <- function(df_col, data = dfTdata, give_back = ''){
      othernames <- names(dfTdata)[!names(dfTdata) == df_col]
      coldifs <- lapply(othernames, function(x) mean(abs(data[[x]] - data[[df_col]]), na.rm = TRUE))
      names(coldifs) <- othernames
      min_col_ind <- which(unlist(coldifs) == min(unlist(coldifs)))
      min_col <- names(min_col_ind)
      if(give_back == 'name'){
        return(min_col)
      }else if(give_back == 'info'){
        return(coldifs[min_col])
      }else{
        return(data[[min_col]])
      }
    }

    # Use like this
    funcDiff('TrWindDateTime')
    funcDiff('TrWindDateTime', give_back = 'info')
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me with this suggestion.  When I run funcDiff(TrWindDateTimegive_back = 'info') it returns SteamDateTime, but I know from running AVG(datediff(mi, TrWindDateTime, WindDateTime) in sql server that the field that actually has the smallest average difference from TrWindDateTime is WindDateTime.  SteamDateTime actually has the 2nd largest average difference from TrWindDateTime, of any of the fields in the dataset.  Do you know why the funcDiff would be returning it?

Comment: The issue seems to be with the "coldifs <- lapply(othernames, function(x) mean(abs(data[[x]] - data[[df_col]]), na.rm = TRUE))".  I ran abs(data[[x]] - data[[df_col]]) for a few of the columns like TrWindDateTime and SteamDate and it's returning much smaller numbers than the actual difference in seconds.  abs(data[[x]] - data[[df_col]]) seems to work just fine for TrWindDateTime and WindDateTime.

Comment: I added an update to your code suggestion.  I got your code to work by using difftime with units='secs' for the time difference.  The updated code now works correctly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To give you another option, below is a version that does this with the `data.table` package.  In the function below the result will be the difference and the name of the column as well.  You can also specify the units that you want the difference to be in.

```
library(data.table)

#------------------------------------------------------
# Turn into a data.table and convert to datetime class
#------------------------------------------------------

dfTdata <- as.data.table(dfTdata)
nms <- names(dfTdata)
dfTdata[, (nms) := lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct, origin = '1970-01-01'), .SDcol = nms]

#--------------------------------
# Function to calculate min time
#--------------------------------

findMinAvgTime <- function(ds, var, unit = 'mins'){
  difunits <- c("auto", "secs", "mins", "hours", "days", "weeks")
  stopifnot(unit %in%  difunits, !('data.table' %in% class(ds)),
            !(var %in% names(ds)))

  # Variables to subtract on
  othVras <- setdiff(names(ds), var)

  # Calculate Differences and Mean
  res <- 
    ds[, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
            mean(as.numeric(difftime(get(var), x, units = unit)),
                 na.rm = TRUE)),
       .SDcol = othVras]

  # Unlist the table to a vector
  minres <- unlist(res[, (var) := NULL])

  return(minres[minres == min(minres)])
}

#--------------------------------
# Run Function
#--------------------------------

findMinAvgTime(dfTdata, 'TrWindDateTime')
```

Comment: You're not updating the *input object* by reference within the function.. There's no need for `copy(dt)`.

Comment: @Arun, thanks for that.  For functions that may be expanded later, I include the `copy` to make sure nothing unexpected happens to my original object.  Thanks again for pointing that out.

Comment: @JHamburg  Thank you so much for this example.  I tried running the code though that you supplied and I got the following error:  "Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'ds' not found."  Do you know what would cause that, or are there any changes I need to make to the code before running it?

Comment: @ndderwerdo, I edited the original post to remove a `copy` statement via Arun's comment.  I forgot to update the rest of the function to account for that and now updated the parameters for the function so that `ds` is included --- originally the `dt` object was copied to create object `ds`

Comment: @JHamburg  Thank you for updating the code to resolve the ds issue.  I tried running the new version of the code and now I'm getting a different error: " Error: !("data.table" %in% class(ds)) is not TRUE", do you know what would cause this?